# R Density Graph: How can I add a solid line from the x-axis to the top of the density curve

Tags: r, line, graphing

I have a density plot graphed using:

```
plot(density(x))
```

What I am interested in doing is creating a line for something like x = 5 from the x-axis to the corresponding spot on the curve.

Like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by first storing the density values in an object, and then retrieving the `x` and `y` elements from this object.  In the following example I use `findInterval` to retrieve the y-value for the given x-value:

```
x <- rnorm(1000) # Sample data
y <- density(x)  # Calculate and store density

x0 <- 2 # Desired position on x-axis
y0 <- y$y[findInterval(x0, y$x)] # Corresponding y value

plot(density(x))
segments(x0, 0, x0, y0)
```

[image]

Comment: I got it to work with your code, now I am off to figure it out with my stuff. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really z-scores then just actually plot the density function `dnorm()`.  It also looks like you'd like to have your actual x-axis at 0.

```
zmax <- 4
curve(dnorm, -zmax, zmax, xaxt = 'n', bty = 'n')
axis(1, -zmax:zmax, pos = 0)
```

To draw in your line you can use the `dnorm` function again.

```
zscore <- 1.65
segments(zscore, 0, zscore, dnorm(zscore))
```

You could also even shade it out nicely... :)

```
x <- seq(zscore, zmax, 0.01)
y <- c(0, dnorm(x)[1:(length(x)-2)],0)
polygon(x,y, density = 20)
```

You can also use `segments` and the `text` command to put the labels right on your graph of what the shaded and unshaded areas mean.
[image: thegraph]